# Making selected value of option with php

Tags: php

I want to make a code which demonstrates that if I choose any option value and press submit button, the value which I chose should be seen in the options box.
The codes are;

```
<?php

    $myfile = fopen("cars_lab5.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    ?>
```

This is to open the file because I pull the items from a file.

```
<?php
        $index = 0;
        $val = $_GET['car'];
        //$selection = "";
        for ($index=0 ; $index < 5 ; $index++){
            $num = 0;
            $line = fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
            $slide = explode("|",$line);    
            //echo '<option value="' . $index . '">' . $slide[$num] . ' - ' . $slide[num+1] . ' euros';     
            if ($val==0){
            echo '<option value="' . $index . '"' . $selection . ' selected">' . $slide[$num] . ' - ' . $slide[num+1] . ' euros'; } 
                else if ($val==1){
            echo '<option value="' . $index . '"' . $selection . ' selected">' . $slide[$num] . ' - ' . $slide[num+1] . ' euros'; } 
                else if ($val==2){
            echo '<option value="' . $index . '"' . $selection . ' selected">' . $slide[$num] . ' - ' . $slide[num+1] . ' euros'; } 
                else if ($val==3){
            echo '<option value="' . $index . '"' . $selection . ' selected">' . $slide[$num] . ' - ' . $slide[num+1] . ' euros'; } 
                else if ($val==4){
            echo '<option value="' . $index . '"' . $selection . ' selected">' . $slide[$num] . ' - ' . $slide[num+1] . ' euros'; } 

        }
        fclose($myfile);
        ?>
```

When I use this code, everything works properly but if I choose third option and press submit button, again first item is seen on the option box instead of what I choose.

Comment: WTF is that if that `if`. you're printing the *same* thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set all options with the 'selected' tag, so the browser will show the last option as selected by default.

You need to remove the 'selected' string from the echo statement and configure the $selection var somewhere:

```
$selection=($index==$val?'selected':null)
```

You don't need the if/else statement at all.

So you would just have one line:

```
echo '<option value="' . $index . '"' . $selection . '">' . $slide[$num] . ' - ' . $slide[num+1] . ' euros';
```

**EDIT  including example as per comment**
Your example code will look like:

```
<?php
        $index = 0;
        $val = $_GET['car'];
        //$selection = "";
        for ($index=0 ; $index < 5 ; $index++){
            $num = 0;
            $line = fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
            $slide = explode("|",$line);    
$selection=($index==$val?'selected':null);

               echo '<option value="' . $index . '"' . $selection . '">' . $slide[$num] . ' - ' . $slide[num+1] . ' euros'; 

        }
        fclose($myfile);
        ?>
```

Comment: Could you please reorganize my codes with my style ? I couldn't embed your codes to mine, I took error. @matwr

Comment: sure please see edit. Although you will need to test the rest of your code, my answer is specific to your question about the select element.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home1-2/b/buraku/public_html/E-commerce/technology.php on line 216

I took this error when I copied your selection code line.

Comment: its just a missing ; I've added it to the answer

Comment: I embedded your code and it worked well but the option box still shows everytime the first element :)

Comment: have you checked the html output from the browser, CTRL + U paste the part of the source code where your <select> element appears. You may also want to add autocomplete='off' to the element.